# How to check Alamofire request has completed

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am developing an **iPad** application using **Swift**. For http requests I use **Alamofire** library. So far I have managed to pull some data from an API. But the problem is since it is an asynchronous call I don't know how to check whether the request has completed. Any help would be appreciated.

This is the code I have implemented so far

**Client class**

```
func getUsers(completionHandler: ([User]?, NSError?) -> ()) -> (){

    var users: [User] = []
    let parameters = [
        "ID": "123",
        "apikey": "1234",
    ]

    Alamofire.request(.GET, "API_URL", parameters: parameters).responseJSON() {
        (_, _, JSON, error) in
        let items = (JSON!.valueForKey("Users") as! [NSDictionary])
        for item in items {
            var user: User = User()
            user.userId = item.valueForKey("ID")! as? String
            user.userName = item.valueForKey("Name")! as? String
            user.group = item.valueForKey("Group")! as? String
            users.append(user)
        }
        completionHandler(users, error)
    }

}
```

**Main class**

```
func getUsers(){
    FacilityClient().getUsers() { (users, error) -> Void in
        if users != nil {
            self.users = users!
        } else{
            println("error - \(error)")
        }
    }
    tableUsers.reloadData()
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closure part of the **Alamofire request** is called, when the request has completed. I've used your code and commented the line where the request hast finished:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "API_URL", parameters: parameters).responseJSON() {
        (_, _, JSON, error) in
      //
      // The request has finished here. Check if error != nil before doing anything else here.
      //            
        let items = (JSON!.valueForKey("Users") as! [NSDictionary])
        for item in items {
            var user: User = User()
            user.userId = item.valueForKey("ID")! as? String
            user.userName = item.valueForKey("Name")! as? String
            user.group = item.valueForKey("Group")! as? String
            users.append(user)
        }
      //
      // After creating the user array we will call the completionHandler, which probably reports back to a ViewController instance
      //
        completionHandler(users, error)
    }
```

Comment: So by the time I call "tableUsers.reloadData()" the "users" has been loaded completely?

Comment: If `getUsers()` is the method which calls the **Alamofire** request in your question then yes.

Comment: But no. I have checked it. When I set it to a timer, it loads the table. Otherwise not loading

Comment: Have you checked the `length`of your **items**? If it's 0 than then users `array` will be empty

Comment: I think that method will not work correctly. Because if all the users are not pulled when I check that it will show only few

Comment: I did not understand your last comment. Your question was: **How to check Alamofire request has completed** I can only tell you that the closure, which is called with the `JSON` and `error` objects means, that the request has finished.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the `tableView` to reload data after successfully fetching data over network, you will need to call `tableUsers.reloadData()` inside that completion handler, like this:

```
func getUsers(){
    FacilityClient().getUsers() { (users, error) -> Void in
        if users != nil {
            self.users = users!
            tableUsers.reloadData() // SHOULD be here
        } else{
            println("error - \(error)")
        }
    }
    // tableUsers.reloadData() // WAS here
}
```

And Alamofire make sure the completion handler is called on main queue if you don't specify a queue. You don't need to add code to make it be called on `mainThread` again.

And to your originally question: The only way Alamofire let you know a request has completed is by calling that completion handler which you give to the `Alamofire.request` method.